# Get VPN parameters from tcpdump

Tags: vpn, wireshark

There are some cases when VPN client has no (working) linux-version. Is it possible to run linux openvpn client with proper flags to replace them?

For example - first dump messages between client and server during connection establishment, then get VPM parameters from tcpdump using wireshark and finally run openvpn with proper params?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to get the parameters from the VPN server configuration & documentation than from tcpdump. The connection is encrypted, after all. Of course the details depends on the VPN server and whether it's compatible with OpenVPN or not. (Not enough details to tell.)